# How to open new tab on button click and send post data?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, phtml, html, post-data

I've been trying to make my button open a new tab, the same way my form is doing but I've discovered that `window.open()` doesn't work on POST requests. SO, is there any other way I can make my button open a new tab instead of opening in the parent tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to place the `target="_blank"` like so

```
<form id="annex" method="POST" target="_blank" action="checkbutton/index/display">
    <input name='monkey' type="hidden" value="<?= $block->getProduct()->getSku(); ?>"/>
    <button type="submit" class="action primary tocart" id="checkstores"><?=__('Check Stores')?></button>
</form>
```